# What would be the practical implications of trying EXWM (Emacs Window Manager) in my macOS machine concerning the native macOS applications?

Tags: applications, software-recommendation, x11, emacs

I have been using a Macbook Air M1 for professional reasons and would like to amplify Emacs in my life.

I have been searching for the introduction of EXWM in my workflow. Unfortunately, as I started [reading the official documentation](https://github-wiki-see.page/m/ch11ng/exwm/wiki/Installation-on-macOS) I discovered that there are some limitations.

In particular:

> Note that EXWM cannot manage native macOS applications at all, only X11 applications will be managed.

This worries me. After following the instructions on [this source](https://www.macrumors.com/how-to/tell-apps-optimized-for-m1-apple-silicon-macs/), I found some of the native macOS applications I have been currently using:

[image]

You can see important stuff for my workflow. Like, "zoom" (used for professional meetings). Or [karabiner-elements](https://github.com/pdelfino/my-karabiner-elements-config) (heavily used by me to Emacsfy my macOS experience).

What are the practical implications of trying EXWM on my machine? For instance, will Emacs hang if I try zoom?

Obs.: I was in doubt about opening this question in emacs.stackexchange or here. I opened [it there](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/75544/what-will-be-the-practical-implications-of-trying-exwm-in-my-macos-machine-conce) and someone suggested posting it here.

Comment: When they say it can't manage native windows, they mean it won't affect them at all. It only affects things that already run in XQuartz

Comment: Thanks, @Ezekiel. But,  what would happen when I try to use Zoom? Would the application load at least? Would it load but I won't be able to "see the application"? Would it be in some unachievable background?

Comment: If you open the regular Zoom app on macOS it'll open like normal, since it doesn't use XQuartz

Comment: Even if it is a macOS running EXWM?

Since EXWM is the way "I change the focus of the application in hand", how would I change to Zoom?

Comment: You can't have macOS run EXWM that's my point, only XQuartz - well, I think based on everything I know. Perhaps I'm wrong

Comment: ok, thank you, @Ezekiel.